# HTML textboxes are not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, keydown, preventdefault

I want to redirect from current to nextpage on `F1` button click. The page redirects properly, but the textboxes of the current page are not working.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("body").keydown(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        if (event.keyCode === 112) {
            window.location.href = "../nextpage.aspx";
        }
    });
});
```

What should I do to resolve the issue?

Comment: `event` should be `e` in `event.keyCode`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Currently your "preventDefault()" fires in *all* circumstances, stopping the other keys from working properly. You really only need to do that if you detect that the key is F1 specifically:

**Demo of non-working code:**

Note that it's not possible to type anything into the textbox because every key's default behaviour is suppressed.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("body").keydown(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (e.keyCode === 112) {
      window.location.href = "../nextpage.aspx";
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" />
```

**Fixed version:**

I simply move the preventDefault() inside the if statement which detects the exact key pressed.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("body").keydown(function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode === 112) {
      e.preventDefault();
      window.location.href = "../nextpage.aspx";
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text"/>
```

P.S. I also fixed the `e` / `event` mixup in your `if` statement.

Answer (score 2):

change `if (e.keyCode === 112)`  instead of `if (event.keyCode === 112)`

Answer (score 2):

`e.preventDefault();` is preventing all keypresses in your page.
simply change your code like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("body").keydown(function (e) {
        if (e.keyCode === 112) {
            e.preventDefault();
            window.location.href = "../nextpage.aspx";
        }
     });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

## Problem:

You define `event` as `e` but use it as `event`

## Code :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $("body").keydown(function (e) {
            if (e.keyCode === 112) { // error was here
                e.preventDefault(); // should be inside if statement
                window.location.href = "../nextpage.aspx";
            }
   });
});
```

## Updated code (a lil better) :

```
$(document).ready( () => $("body").keydown((e) => e.keyCode == 112&&(e.preventDefault(),(window.location.href= "../nextpage.aspx"))));
```